# How to Bunzip a file stored

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, bzip2

I have to archive the HDFS files frequently. The files have to be compressed in the Bunzip format using Java code. Now, what I did is the following:

1. Move the input files to a local location `hdfs.moveToLocalFile`
2. bzip using the `bzip2` command.
3. Move the .bz2 files to the HDFS to another location`hdfs.moveFromLocalFile`.

I'm using Hadoop 1.1.2 version. Is there any API available to bzip the files directly, without local copy and BZip?

Also now I'm using the linux shell command to BZip the files. Can somebody help me how to do the BZip command using Java code?

Comment: I achieved the goal to BZip hdfs files with out copying it locally. I thought I'll share the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void addFile(String source, String destination, Configuration paramConfiguration) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    FileSystem localFileSystem = FileSystem.get(paramConfiguration);
    String str1 = paramString1.substring(source.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, source.length());
    if (destination.charAt(destination.length() - 1) != '/') {
        destination = destination + "/" + str1;
    } else {
        destination = destination + str1;
    }
    BZip2Codec localBZip2Codec = new BZip2Codec();
    String str2 = localBZip2Codec.getDefaultExtension();
    Path localPath = new Path(paramString2 + str2);

    CompressionOutputStream localCompressionOutputStream = localBZip2Codec.createOutputStream(localFileSystem.create(localPath));

    IOUtils.copyBytes(localFileSystem.open(new Path(paramString1)), localCompressionOutputStream, 4096, true);
}
```